# How to query date field of json object in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

imagine a PostgreSQL 9.3 with a table that has an sql column that contains an object:

```
{"start":"2016-02-04 00:45:56.000"}
```

How could I query it to get objects with start date > :"2016-01-01 00:00:00.000"?

This question is specificly for **version 9.3**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (c->>'start')::timestamp with time zone > '2016-01-01'::timestamp with time zone;
```

I assume that the table is called `mytable` and the JSON column is called `c`. This also assumes that the times are in UTC. If your time is in local time, use `timestamp without time zone` instead.

Comment: Thank you @redneb ! It's the time zone that is the secret source that I couldn't figure out on my own :)